# SQL Query takes too much time when retrieving data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select 
  * 
from 
  [platformnew].[dbo].[users] u 
where u.Phone not in 
  (select case  
    when convert(varchar(100),phonenumber) <> '' then convert(varchar(100),ISNULL(PhoneNumber,0)) 
    else convert(varchar(100),0)
  end phonenumber 
  from 
     [ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer]
  ) 
and u.Phone not in 
  (select case  
    when convert(varchar(100),phonenumber2) <> '' then convert(varchar(100),ISNULL(PhoneNumber2,0)) 
    else convert(varchar(100),0) 
  end phonenumber2 
  from [ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer]
  ) 
and u.Email not in 
  (select ISNULL(Email,'') 
  from [ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer])
and u.Email not in 
  (select ISNULL(Email2,'') 
  from [ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer])
```

this query takes too much time to execute,i think it takes around 3 more minutes,please help me to solve it

Comment: first you should specify which DB system you use, be it Oracle, Mysql or any other, second if you wish to increase the speed you have to show the tables' structure

Comment: And possibly the size of the table, of a single row, and the number of the records.

Comment: You should remove the `CONVERT()` and `ISNULL()`function calls...

Comment: it is sql server

Comment: You mean M$ SQL Server...

Comment: obviously we don't know the structure and the relationships but I'd suspect there don't necessarily need to be so many subqueries.

Comment: the users table contains 1678 data and mp customer table contains 82508 data

Comment: Can `convert(varchar(100),phonenumber)` resolve to empty string? If it is a numeric field, it can be NULL, or a numeric value. None of which would be converted to empty string...

Comment: there is no relation ship between these table.the two tables are containing in different database with same server

Comment: Avoid using * when selecting data, try to name the table columns you need and by doing that will help to reduce the query processing time

Comment: Execution plan/indexes table structure?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the Not in to not Exists like this for example

```
select 
  * 
from 
  [platformnew].[dbo].[users] u 
where u.Phone not exists
  (select  1 from 
     [ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer]
     WHERE   convert(varchar(100),ISNULL([ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer].PhoneNumber,0)) = u.Phone
  )
```

and for the convert part you only need isnull `convert(varchar(100),ISNULL([ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer].PhoneNumber,0))`
just remove the case when

Answer (score 0):

You should see performance increase when you change all `NOT IN` clauses to `NOT EXISTS`. E.g:

```
and not exists
  (
    select 1
    from [ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer] mpc
    where u.Phone = mpc.Phone
  )
```

Also, all `CONVERT` functions are unnecessary. If phonenumber data type is `int`, then write your clauses using this type, e.g `isnull(phonenumber,0)<>0`. And if phone numbers should not be null or 0, add it as separate conditions, because now every time when it's null or 0, you unnecessarily look up other tables to find null and 0 there to discard it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [platformnew].[dbo].[users] u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [ecommerce_crm].[dbo].[mpcustomer] c
    WHERE c.phonenumber = u.Phone
        OR c.phonenumber2 = u.Phone
        OR c.Email = u.Email 
        OR c.Email2 = u.Email 
    )
    AND u.Phone != '0'
    AND u.Email != ''
```

Comment: Thanks mr denis now its coming under 14 seconds.